# How to connect to SQL Server Analysis Server via Management Studio command line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, ssas

I can connect SQL Server Management Studio to a SQL DB by passing command line parameters like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\....\Ssms.exe" -E -S SERVERNAME -d DB_NAME -nosplash
```

(Obviously -E is for window Authentication)

This connects to the SQL Server. But I often find I want to connect to an Analysis Server instance instead. Can anyone tell me the command line option please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one.

[image: SSMS command-line options help screen]

But... why open and close Management Studio all the time? Leave it open and use the Registered Servers list (View | Registered Servers).

Comment: In my work I login  to multiple clients over the course of a day and have to log in and out.

Comment: @PreetSangha: So for each client you would need to set up a shortcut... why not set up Registered Servers instead? You'll undoubtedly need access to other servers as well.

Comment: Will look into it. Will registered servers give me the full break down of objects like sps, tables etc?

Comment: @PreetSangha: Registered Servers is just a saved, organized list of servers: it makes connecting to servers easier (less typing). You can also use it to leverage multi-server queries and Policy-Based Management over server infrastructure.

Comment: @PreetSangha: You're welcome. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a parameter which will make that happen.  None of the documented parameters will tell it to switch to another instance type.